# Voice chat distorted and cutting out while gaming

Tags: audio, drivers, gaming, chat, voice

While playing a game and using voice chat (using either Discord or Teamspeak), the voice chat goes all robotic and keeps cutting out. I sound robotic to my friends, and my friends to me. When I close the game (e.g. the new Call of Duty, or CS:GO) the problem goes away and I can communicate with my friends again. It seems that whenever my pc is under heavy load, it happens.

So far I've tried:

- set the priority of Discord to high in the task manager;
- made the microphone/headset my default communications device;
- unchecked "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device";
- updated my drivers;
- updated my motherboard firmware;
- tried a different internet cable;
- tried a different microphone;
- reinstalled Windows 10;
- reassembled and cleaned the pc;
- ran the Windows Memory Diagnostizc (result: The Windows Memory Diagnostic tested the computer's memory and detected no errors);

but the problem persists. Does anyone have any idea? [This](https://nl.pcpartpicker.com/user/jobterhorst/saved/#view=9mRZRB) is my build. It starts happening when core 1 of my cpu goes up to around 40 degrees Celsius.
Thanks in advance.

CPU: Intel Core i5-6500 3.2 GHz Quad-Core Processor

CPU Cooler: Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO

Motherboard: MSI B150I GAMING PRO Mini ITX LGA1151

Memory: Kingston HyperX Fury Black 8 GB (1 x 8 GB) DDR4-2133

Storage: Samsung 850 EVO-Series 250 GB 2.5" Solid State Drive

Video Card: Asus GeForce GTX 1060 6GB 6 GB Strix Video Card

Power Supply: Corsair Builder 600 W 80+ Bronze Certified ATX Power Supply

Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro OEM 64-bit

Comment: Add to your question: MB Manu/Model, Graphics Manu/Model, cpu manu/model, broadband speedtest results before and during game. clarify whether you sound robot, friends sound robot or everybody sounds robot.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:
- type on search manage audio devices
- choose the recording tab
- double left click on the mic and choose advanced tab
- make sure the boxe "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device" is active
- restart your pc.

hope it help.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried your solution and the problem has not gone away unfortunately.

Comment: try to check this article, i found out this is actually a common problem. https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-stop-robotic-voice-issues-on-discord/